# Bluetooth adaptor connection problem

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I have a Bluetooth adapter which is connected to speaker. I can successfully connected to android cellphone and can play any songs you can hear it from Bluetooth speaker. But when I try to connect the Ubuntu laptop it gets connected but sound does not come from the Bluetooth connected speaker. I tried to see the sound settings. It looks something like this:

[image]

May I know what is the symbol at Handsfree device and how can I get the sound from the Bluetooth speaker. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: does it shows connected in bluetooth settings?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Yeah it shows connected to Bluetooth and also Bluetooth adapter blinking properly when it gets connected. But still when I select the handsfree in the sound setting the sound is still coming from laptop speaker.

Comment: I dont know what exactly is in your case; but this happens to me sometimes with my bluetooth headphones, so what I do is first I switch on the bluetooth of my headphones and keep it that way for 20-30 seconds and then switch on my laptop's bluetooth and then connect and it works fine. If I switch on bluetooth of both and connect immediately then I sound does not comes in bluetooth headphone, weird. you should try my method